signed overflow warning when extracting/inserting a timepoint from/to streams
When specifying the command line options -Wstrict-overflow=4 and -O3, extracting a timepoint (e.g. std::chrono::local_seconds) from a stream object triggers some warnings from GCC (v14.1). Inserting a timepoint to a stream object triggers some warnings as well.
This is not the case with Clang though. It doesn't show any warnings despite specifying -stdlib=libstdc++.
On GCC, the warnings appear even with -O1 or O2 but not with -Og or -O0 or -Os.
A minimal example:
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::chrono::local_seconds tp;
    std::cin >> std::chrono::parse( "%F %T", tp );
    if ( std::cin )
        std::cout << tp << '\n';
}

All of the warnings are related to signed overflow somehow. But they all disappear when -Wstrict-overflow=2 is used instead.
Should this be concerning?
The warning message:
<source>: In member function 'std::basic_istream<_CharT2, _Traits2>& std::chrono::__detail::_Parser<_Duration>::operator()(std::basic_istream<_CharT2, _Traits2>&, const _CharT*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT2, _Traits2, _Alloc>*, std::chrono::minutes*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; _Duration = std::chrono::duration<long int>]':
<source>:12:1: warning: assuming signed overflow does not occur when changing X +- C1 cmp C2 to X cmp C2 -+ C1 [-Wstrict-overflow]
   12 | }
      | ^
<source>: In constructor 'constexpr std::chrono::hh_mm_ss<_Duration>::hh_mm_ss(_Duration) [with _Duration = std::chrono::duration<long int>]':
<source>:12:1: warning: assuming signed overflow does not occur when determining that expression is always non-negative [-Wstrict-overflow]
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.1.0/include/c++/14.1.0/chrono:41,
                 from <source>:2:
In function 'constexpr typename std::common_type<std::chrono::duration<_Rep1, _Period1>, std::chrono::duration<_Rep2, _Period2> >::type std::chrono::operator-(const duration<_Rep1, _Period1>&, const duration<_Rep2, _Period2>&) [with _Rep1 = long int; _Period1 = std::ratio<1>; _Rep2 = long int; _Period2 = std::ratio<60>]',
    inlined from 'constexpr std::chrono::hh_mm_ss<_Duration>::hh_mm_ss(_Duration, bool) [with _Duration = std::chrono::duration<long int>]' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.1.0/include/c++/14.1.0/chrono:2338:55,
    inlined from 'constexpr std::chrono::hh_mm_ss<_Duration>::hh_mm_ss(_Duration) [with _Duration = std::chrono::duration<long int>]' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.1.0/include/c++/14.1.0/chrono:2369:49,
    inlined from 'static decltype(auto) std::__format::__formatter_chrono<_CharT>::_S_hms(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int> >; _CharT = char]' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.1.0/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/chrono_io.h:1433:21:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.1.0/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/chrono.h:716:41: warning: assuming signed overflow does not occur when determining that expression is always non-negative [-Wstrict-overflow]
  716 |         return __cd(__cd(__lhs).count() - __cd(__rhs).count());
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>: In static member function 'static decltype(auto) std::__format::__formatter_chrono<_CharT>::_S_hms(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int> >; _CharT = char]':
<source>:12:1: warning: assuming signed overflow does not occur when determining that expression is always non-negative [-Wstrict-overflow]
   12 | }
      | ^
<source>:12:1: warning: assuming signed overflow does not occur when determining that expression is always non-negative [-Wstrict-overflow]
In function 'constexpr typename std::common_type<std::chrono::duration<_Rep1, _Period1>, std::chrono::duration<_Rep2, _Period2> >::type std::chrono::operator-(const duration<_Rep1, _Period1>&, const duration<_Rep2, _Period2>&) [with _Rep1 = long int; _Period1 = std::ratio<1>; _Rep2 = long int; _Period2 = std::ratio<60>]',
    inlined from 'constexpr std::chrono::hh_mm_ss<_Duration>::hh_mm_ss(_Duration, bool) [with _Duration = std::chrono::duration<long int>]' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.1.0/include/c++/14.1.0/chrono:2338:55,
    inlined from 'constexpr std::chrono::hh_mm_ss<_Duration>::hh_mm_ss(_Duration) [with _Duration = std::chrono::duration<long int>]' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.1.0/include/c++/14.1.0/chrono:2369:49,
    inlined from 'typename _FormatContext::iterator std::__format::__formatter_chrono<_CharT>::_M_format_to_ostream(const _Tp&, _FormatContext&, bool) const [with _Tp = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int> >; _FormatContext = std::basic_format_context<std::__format::_Sink_iter<char>, char>; _CharT = char]' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.1.0/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/chrono_io.h:720:16:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.1.0/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/chrono.h:716:41: warning: assuming signed overflow does not occur when determining that expression is always non-negative [-Wstrict-overflow]
  716 |         return __cd(__cd(__lhs).count() - __cd(__rhs).count());
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>: In member function 'typename _FormatContext::iterator std::__format::__formatter_chrono<_CharT>::_M_format_to_ostream(const _Tp&, _FormatContext&, bool) const [with _Tp = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int> >; _FormatContext = std::basic_format_context<std::__format::_Sink_iter<char>, char>; _CharT = char]':
<source>:12:1: warning: assuming signed overflow does not occur when determining that expression is always non-negative [-Wstrict-overflow]
   12 | }
      | ^
<source>:12:1: warning: assuming signed overflow does not occur when determining that expression is always non-negative [-Wstrict-overflow]
In function 'constexpr unsigned int std::chrono::__detail::__add_modulo(unsigned int, _Tp) [with unsigned int __d = 7; _Tp = long int]',
    inlined from 'static constexpr std::chrono::weekday std::chrono::weekday::_S_from_days(const std::chrono::days&)' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.1.0/include/c++/14.1.0/chrono:973:58,
    inlined from 'constexpr std::chrono::weekday::weekday(const std::chrono::sys_days&)' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.1.0/include/c++/14.1.0/chrono:986:29,
    inlined from 'std::basic_istream<_CharT2, _Traits2>& std::chrono::__detail::_Parser<_Duration>::operator()(std::basic_istream<_CharT2, _Traits2>&, const _CharT*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT2, _Traits2, _Alloc>*, std::chrono::minutes*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; _Duration = std::chrono::duration<long int>]' at /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.1.0/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/chrono_io.h:4156:18:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.1.0/include/c++/14.1.0/chrono:533:40: warning: assuming signed overflow does not occur when changing X +- C1 cmp C2 to X cmp C2 -+ C1 [-Wstrict-overflow]
  533 |         auto const __offset = __y >= 0 ? _Up(0) : __modulo_offset<__d, _Tp>();
      |                               ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Is this a flaw in GCC? Like some false positive? Because this warning option doesn't annoy other parts of my program. Only the I/O parts.

This is why you should always build your code with different compilers, with various optimization levels and on different platforms. It all helps to spot different problems.

Neither a flow, nor false positive. The first and the last warnings assume that a code like x + 1 < 2 can be converted to x < 1. Other warnings assume non negative values are returned, and using unsigned types may be better.

It seems to me just to be a particular case of the fact that signed integer overflow causes undefined behavior, and compilers can assume it never occurs.  This particular option with this particular compiler is just highlighting some of the specific places where it's taking advantage of that assumption in specific ways; it's not surprising that different compilers or different options would differ.

If you're really worried, you'd have to audit the library code.  Most likely it suggests issues that could only arise when time values are close to the limits for the type. If you're on a system with 32-bit times, this might determine exactly how close you can get to the year 2038 before things start to go wrong.  With 64-bit times, you probably don't have to worry for the next few billion years.

@NateEldredge I think I should opt for the default argument which is 2. It does not bring up these warnings. It's not a problem in my code after all. It's part of the std library.

This is worthy of a bug report to gcc's libstdc++.  There's nothing wrong with your minimal example.  And there's probably nothing wrong with the libstdc++ implementation either.  It probably just needs some warning suppression.
